# Is there any way to set the max schedule time for Google Cloud Tasks to more than 720 hours?

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-tasks

We are using Google Cloud Tasks to manage timing a messaging queue in Firebase Functions, and need to schedule some follow up messages more than a month out. We are getting this error:

`3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: The Task.scheduleTime, 2021-05-09T02:00:00-08:00, is too far in the future. Schedule time must be no more than 720h in the future.`

Which is documented here: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/quotas

Google enables you to configure virtually every other setting (https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/configuring-queues) but I don't see any way around this limitation. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, in some resources you can request an increase in quota, but sadly with `Maximum schedule time for a task` is not possible, it appears to be fixed at 30 days.

What you could use is Cloud Scheduler, which might be more appropriate for your needs. You can check when to use one or the other in [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-tasks-sched).

Another workaround if you really want to use Cloud Tasks, you can create 2 separate queues, as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64633877/15747954) propose.